# Reference `description` from `markdownDescription` in VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, schema

I am defining a schema to validate and help fill some fields in a YAML file.

Take this YAML file (with just one field) as an example:

```yaml
some_field:
```

Now, I want a title, type and description in the schema. E.g., something like:

```json
"some_field": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Some basic description."
}
```

I learned that there is this `markdownDescription` field specifically in VS Code, which I'd like to use. Mainly to point the user to some documentation files (i.e. links). Is there a way to have `markdownDescription` reference `description`? I want to preserve `description` and avoid duplicating text.

```json
"some_field": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Some basic description. [Link](https://example.com)!"
    "markdownDescription": "Some basic description. [Link](https://example.com)!"
}
```

have something like:

```json
"some_field": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Some basic description.",
    "markdownDescription": "${this.description}. [Link](https://example.com)!"
}
```